# Javascript Closures trying to set up a function with 6 object keys

Tags: javascript, constructor, closures

This object sets first, last and full name and also gets first, last and fullname.
here is my code

```js
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
    
    var nameArray = firstAndLast.split(' ');  
    this.first = nameArray[0].toString();
    this.last = nameArray[1].toString();
    
    this.setFirstName = function(name){
     this.first = name;
    };
    this.setLastName = function(name){
     this.last = name;
    };
    this.setFullName = function(name){
     name = firstAndLast;
     name = name.split(' ');
      this.first = name[0].toString();
      this.last = name[1].toString();
    };
    this.getFirstName = function(){
     return this.first;
    };
    this.getLastName = function(){
     return this.last;
    };
    this.getFullName = function(){
     return this.first + " " + this.last;
    };
    return firstAndLast;
};


var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');

app.innerHTML = bob.getLastName() + "\n" + bob.getFirstName() + "\n" + bob.getFullName();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

this code works but have 8 object keys. How can I make this code work with only 6 Object keys.

Comment: which one do you need?

Comment: FYI, there is no need for these methods to be created inside the constructor. They can be defined on the prototype. Also, `return firstAndLast;` has no effect. In general, having getter and setter methods like this is not that common in JavaScript.

Comment: Also, why does it matter how many properties the object has? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: the problem asks me to add 6 object keys it can not be more than 6 and it has test to see if all the methods work and if there are more than 6 object keys.

Comment: the problem starts off as and empty function with firstAndLast as the parameter and return firstAndLast at the bottom of the function.

Comment: I assume the whole point of the exercise is that you learn and understand the application of closures. Given you the solution would defeat the purpose of that exercise. I can give you a hint though: None of the functions you define access variables defined outside of them. The solution to the problem is to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to get rid of, but it will be much simpler if you use accessor properties like this:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
  }
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
  set fullName(name) {
    name = name.split(' ');
    this.firstName = name[0];
    this.lastName = name[1];
  }
}
var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');
console.log(bob.lastName + "\n" + bob.firstName + "\n" + bob.fullName);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i'm going to try to implement this.